# Kafka MQTT connector with multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are using Kafka-Mqtt connector from Confluent team. Is there any way to publish data from **multiple Mqtt topics** to **multiple Kafka topics** with same name as of Mqtt , i.e test1 in Mqtt -> test1 in kafka so on. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple MQTT Source connectors in order to replicate data from distinct topics:

For example,

```
{
  "config" : {
    "name" : "MqttSourceConnector1",
    "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "mqtt.server.uri" : "< Required Configuration >",
    "mqtt.topics" : "topic_1"
  }
}
```

and,

```
  {
      "config" : {
        "name" : "MqttSourceConnector2",
        "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "mqtt.server.uri" : "< Required Configuration >",
        "mqtt.topics" : "topic_2"
      }
    }
```

Comment: This applies to all Connects, not just MQTT

Comment: @cricket_007 Correct.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous what if I have many MQTT topics ? Isn't it too many connectors ? What about performance ?

Comment: Number of connectors should not affect performance. Performance is affected by the volume of data which is replicated from/to kafka/mqtt. You need to assign a reasonable amount of resources but as I said number of connectors does not have a major impact on the performance of Kafka Connect. If you want to minimize that impact though, just increase polling intervals.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous Thanks for the reply. One concern I have is that we have many mqtt topics, and some are dynamically created (targeted to a particular use etc, by adding userId to topic (eg: topic_userId )). In this case, it is cumbersome to add connector for each topic separately. Any other way u can suggest ?

Comment: How about writing a bash script that generates (and calls Kafka Connect REST API) for multiple topics?